# Adding/changing application synonyms in search

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop

So I hit the windows key and typed `excel` (before realizing my mistake), and yet the dash search successfully turned up LibreOffice Calc. `cmd` likewise turns up the terminal. `text` yields Vim, Kate, Universal Access and LibreOffice Writer in addition to applications with the word text in them.

I brought up the /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop entry and the only reference to excel is:

```
user@box:/usr/share/applications$ cat libreoffice-calc.desktop | grep excel

MimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet;
...
application/msexcel;
application/vnd.ms-excel;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template;
application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12;
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12;
...
```

and, given it doesn't recognize `msexcel`, I don't think this is where the synonym is coming from.

Where do you set synonyms like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a key called "Keywords", it's described as

> A list of strings which may be used in addition to other metadata to describe this entry. This can be useful e.g. to facilitate searching through entries. The values are not meant for display, and should not be redundant with the values of `Name` or `GenericName`.

For example for *LibreOffice Calc* it looks something like

```
Keywords=Accounting;Stats;OpenDocument Spreadsheet;Chart;Microsoft Excel;Microsoft Works;OpenOffice Calc;ods;xls;xlsx;
```

You can search with any of these keywords, LibreOffice Calc should appear in the result.

Comment: It's capitalized, explains why grep didn't show it. Thanks!

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yep, always use a `-i` ; )